# Plotting with special characters: "▬"

Tags: python, matplotlib, unicode

I have the following code that is suppose to write the ▬ character(alt+22) in the plot scatter. But when I run it it shows "?". Any directions?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import datetime
fig = plt.figure(facecolor="#979899")
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor("#d1d1d1")
plt.grid(True)
plt.title("This is a title",fontsize=32)
plt.xticks([datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,21),datetime.date(2018,11,22)],["11/20","11/21","11/22"])
plt.yticks([0,16,32],["0","16","32"])
x1 = [datetime.date(2018,11,20),datetime.date(2018,11,21),datetime.date(2018,11,22)]
y1 = [18,32,21]
for i,item in enumerate(y1):
    xP = x1[i]
    yP = y1[i]
    plt.text(xP,yP,str(item)+"▬",fontsize=11)
plt.plot(x1,y1,label="Some Legend A")
plt.scatter(x1,y1)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Does the font that you are using support that character?

Comment: Works fine for me: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7WQOJ.png). Check which font you are using and choose a different one if it doesn't have the character.

Comment: Not too familiar with Python, but I'm fairly sure that when "▬" comes out as "?", this is not a problem with the font.